# How save products in basket when close, change activity

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have product basket in my app. Writing for android on c# (Xamarin)

But when I close/change activity it deleting.

Code of adding product in basket from another activity.

```
add.Click += delegate {
    var intent = new Intent (this, typeof(CartActivity));
    intent.PutExtra ("title", (string)(firstitem ["post_title"]));
    intent.PutExtra ("price", (string)(firstitem ["price"] + " грн"));
    intent.PutExtra ("weight", (string)(firstitem ["weight"] + "г"));
    StartActivity (intent);
};
```

Code of receiving product in basket activity

```
productname.Text = Intent.GetStringExtra("title");
price.Text = Intent.GetStringExtra("price");
weight.Text = Intent.GetStringExtra("weight");
```

How I can save products in basket?

Comment: You need to clarify where you want to save..to a local db? to a remote server calling a web service?

Comment: No, Look.

I want to save state of Activity. Like put it on background and resume it when i click on basket button.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save text when I close activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33460924/save-text-when-i-close-activity)

Comment: Another easy way is to use a `singleton class`. This way you have stored item in basket in all activities.

Answer (score 1):

> But when I close/change activity it deleting.

Because sending data to next Activity without saving any where, so if any other Activity is starting or application reopen then data is not available   in basket activity using `getIntent` method.

Easy way is use [SharedPreferences](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Android.Preferences.Preference.SharedPreferences/) for storing and retrieving data :

Example :[How to save user settings](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/8199/how-to-save-user-settings)

Comment: Thank's I will try this and write about result.